# Use callback to get JSON value from call to database

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I am trying to populate a UITable with a json result. I call a function that gets the json from the server and stores the result in `NSDictionary`. I want to be able to use this collection, and then populate a table. I run into a problem however because for the `func numberOfRowsInSection` I need the count of the collection, and since my json result is within another function inside a `try/catch` I cant seem to return the value.

This is what I have for the function which I call in `ViewDidLoad()`:

```
func getSubjects() -> NSDictionary{

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "www.mydomain.com/script.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl as! URL)
    let user_id = UserDetails[0]

    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "user_id=\(user_id)";
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){

        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        var err: NSError?
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {

                let resultValue: NSDictionary = parseJSON["subjects"] as! NSDictionary

            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            err = error
            print(err!);
        }
    }
    task.resume();
}
```

If I print `resultValue` I get what I need, in this example being:

```
{
1 =     (
    Maths,
    Lecture
);
2 =     (
    Science,
    Lecture
);
3 =     (
    English,
    Seminar
);
```

}

But the confusion is, how do I go about returning this value? and where? and how would I implement it in the table? If I try to return `resultValue` when I parse the `JSON` I get the error that it is `unexpected non-void return in void function` and if I try to return the value at the end of the function, I get an `unresolved identifier error`

I feel I am implementing this incorrectly. I have checked many tutorials on this, and no one seems to populate a table with a `POST JSON` so I don't know how to go about returning the value, or the proper method of implementation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated by why are you using Objective-C types in your Swift code? Use Swift dictionary instead of `NSDictionary`, etc.

Comment: Point noted, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem your having is that the dictionary hasn't been retrieved by the time you try to return it. You can use an asynchronous callback to get the dictionary after it has been retrieved from your database.

```
func getSubjects(callback: @escaping (NSDictionary)-> Void){

let myUrl = NSURL(string: "www.mydomain.com/script.php");
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl as! URL)
let user_id = UserDetails[0]

request.httpMethod = "POST";
let postString = "user_id=\(user_id)";
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){

    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    var err: NSError?
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = json {

            let resultValue: NSDictionary = parseJSON["subjects"] as! NSDictionary

            callback(resultValue)

        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        err = error
        print(err!);
    }
}
task.resume();
}
```

and then you would call this function like...

```
getSubjects(callback: {(resultValue)-> Void in 
    print(resultValue)
    //here you could set your tableView data equal to the values in the dictionary that was just received and then call self.tableView.reloadData to update your table view
})
```

So perhaps in the `viewDidLoad()` function of you UITableViewController or in the `viewDidAppear(_:)`, depending on the life cycle of your view, you would call `getSubjects(...)` as i have shown above and then when the callback is called you call `self.tableView.reloadData()` as I have explained in the function call. If you are unsure how to setup a tableview datasource and delegate then you should probably open another question for that

**EDIT**
In response to your comment asking how to use the retrieved value from your server as a variable available to your whole class, you could do something like this...

```
class: ExampleViewController {
    var resultsDictionary: [Int: [String: String]]?

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        getSubjects(callback: {(resultValue)-> Void in 
            resultsDictionary = resultValue
        })
    }

    //Use the actual getSubjects function I have already shown you above
    func getSubjects(){...}


}
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to answer. I have a few queries: (1) `closure use of non escaping parameter may allow it to escape` so I now declare the function as `func getSubjects(callback: @escaping (NSDictionary)-> Void){` (2) Your function call doesn't compile? Unless I'm doing something wrong. In `ViewDidLoad()` I call the function as you did

Comment: Sorry about that. You are right, I missed the `@escaping` before the function parameter and I also missed a `{` in the function call. I have edited my code above it should work now

Comment: Hey Mike, thank you. But while this silences the 'error', I can't actually get the return value? For example, I want to return the count of the dictionary or populate my table. I run the function in the `ViewDidLoad`. I return the `resultValue`. In the `tableView number of rows func` or the `cellForRowAt` I want to access the count of said dictionary and populate the table. How can I? I run the function within that function and I get `Type() has no subscript members`

Comment: well once the callback function is executed then you should set the values in the dictionary as your data for your tableview (depending on which values you want) and then call `self.tableView.reloadData()`. Your original question has 3 questions in it -> " how do I go about returning this value? and where? and how would I implement it in the table?" I have answered the first two. But if you are still unsure how to implement a table view then you need to open up another question as that is a different topic

Comment: to simply get the count of the keys in the dictionary you can use `resultValue.keys.count`

Comment: Okay, leaving the table completely, if I just want `resultValue` to be used in the whole class, I am trying to do: `        let results = getSubjects(callback: {(resultValue)-> Void in
            return resultValue
        })
        print(results)` however this returns an empty set with an error `inferred to have type () which may be unexpected`. How can I just have `resultValue` available to the class as a constant/variable?

Comment: I have included an edit at the bottom of my answer that shows you how to do that. I can't tell what kind of dictionary you need but it looks like you will have a dictionary with keys of type `Int` and values that are also dictionaries which will have keys of type `String` and values of type `String`. In my example I have made the Dictionary an optional value since it won't have a value until the server returns with the JSON

Comment: MikeG, is it possible for you to look at the related question to adding it to a table please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450373/populating-a-uitable-with-nsdictionary-in-swift