# Populating a UITable with NSDictionary in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary that I retrieve from a JSON request and I would like to populate a table with those values. I think everything is okay, however I am getting an error in the class declaration that `Type SubjectsViewController does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'` I am using a storyboard, and I added the table view on the UI to `datasource` and `delegate` and as far as I know, I am implementing the functions correctly. I have added the relevant parts of my code below.

It may be useful to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430429/populate-uitable-with-a-json-result) which is a question I posted to understand why I am using the callback. Thanks in advance!

```
class SubjectsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getSubjects(callback: {(resultValue)-> Void in

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return resultValue.count
            }

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
                cell.textLabel?.text = resultValue[indexPath.row] as! String?
                return cell
            }

        })
    }

    // Initialise components of the view
    let UserDetails = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "UserDetailsArray") ?? [String]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // Function to retrieve the subjects for the user
    func getSubjects(callback: @escaping (NSDictionary)-> Void){

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "www.mydomain.com/retrieveSubjects.php");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl as! URL)
        let user_id = UserDetails[0]
        request.httpMethod = "POST";
        let postString = "user_id=\(user_id)";
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            var err: NSError?
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json {
                    let resultValue: NSDictionary = parseJSON["subjects"] as! NSDictionary
                    callback(resultValue)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                err = error
                print(err!);
            }
        }
        task.resume();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: CLASS throwing unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

```
class SubjectsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var dataDict: [String:AnyObject]?
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
let userDetails: [String] = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey:"UserDetailsArray")!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataDict = [String:AnyObject]()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.getSubjects()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dataDict!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    let array = self.dataDict?[String(indexPath.row)] as! [String]

    print(array)

    cell.textLabel?.text = array[0]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = array[1]
    return cell
}

func getSubjects() {

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "www.mydomain/retrieveSubjects.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl as! URL)
    let user_id = userDetails[0]
    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "user_id=\(user_id)";
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        var err: NSError?
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = json {
                let resultValue = parseJSON["subjects"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                self.dataDict = resultValue
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            err = error
            print(err!);
        }
    }
    task.resume();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you'll need to do:

First, create a class variable for your data. Put this under your class declaration:

```
var dataDict: [String:AnyObject]?
```

Then, to keep things organized, put your tableView property and your userDetails property directly under the dataDict.

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
let userDetails: [String] = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey:"UserDetailsArray")
```

Now, your viewDidLoad method should look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataDict = [String:AnyObject]()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.getSubjects()
}
```

Below that, you'll want to take care of the UITableViewDataSource methods:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dataDict.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    if let array = self.dataDict[String(indexPath.row)] as? [String] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = array[0]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = array[1]
    }
    return cell
}
```

Lastly, you need to implement the `getSubjects()` method:

```
func getSubjects() {

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "www.mydomain.com/retrieveSubjects.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl as! URL)
    let user_id = UserDetails[0]
    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "user_id=\(user_id)";
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        var err: NSError?
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = json {
                let resultValue = parseJSON["subjects"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                self.dataDict = resultValue
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            err = error
            print(err!);
        }
    }
    task.resume();
}
```

Altogether, your code should look like this:

```
class SubjectsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var dataDict: [String:AnyObject]?
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    let userDetails: [String] = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey:"UserDetailsArray")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataDict = [String:AnyObject]()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.getSubjects()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataDict.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        if let array = self.dataDict[String(indexPath.row)] as? [String] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = array[0]
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = array[1]
        }
        return cell
    }

    func getSubjects() {

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "www.mydomain.com/retrieveSubjects.php");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl as! URL)
        let user_id = UserDetails[0]
        request.httpMethod = "POST";
        let postString = "user_id=\(user_id)";
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            var err: NSError?
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json {
                    let resultValue = parseJSON["subjects"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                    self.dataDict = resultValue
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                err = error
                print(err!);
            }
        }
        task.resume();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi BawPotter! Thank you SO much for your response and explaining the answer fully! In the `tableView(cellForRowAt)` function though, resultValue is unresolved? Also, why are most of the functions `overrides`?

Comment: He's assuming this is a UITableViewController. It isn't, so they won't be overrides in your own code.

Comment: @Bawpotter: I replaced resultValue with `dataDict[indexPath.row]` but I get an error that `Type [String:AnyObject]? has no subscript members`

Comment: Could you please copy and paste your JSON data? I'd like to see the way you structured it, that could be the issue.

Comment: Yep it is linked in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430429/populate-uitable-with-a-json-result

Comment: It is a dictionary structured as a string value : then an array of two values

Comment: And you want the first value of the array to show up in the table view cell, correct?

Comment: Well ideally I would like it as a subtitle? With the main label being first value of the array and the subtitle being the 2nd value of the array

Comment: It seems like your dictionary is coded as [Int:AnyObject] and not as [String:AnyObject], considering that your key is a number and not a string. Is that correct?

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the [Int:AnyObject] dictionary. It should work now!

Comment: Thanks BawPotter but still not quite there! I think the key is being recognised as a String value despite being an int so I have changed the declarations to `[String:AnyObject]` and within the `cellForRowAt` I set `self.dataDict?[String(indexPath.row)] as! [String]` but I get an error that `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value` :/ I have posted the entire class in my question

Comment: Wrap the definition of the array in an if let statement, to prevent the error. See my updated code.

Comment: Nevermind, it was my own mistake, I was confused about some keys. Thank you SO SO SO much for your constant help and thorough explanations!

Comment: No problem! Glad I was able to make this work for you.